# How to save in local storage a background-color change in a table cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code that change the background color of a td when user clicks and change to another color when user clicks again, what I'm trying to do is to save that changes in local storage so when users refresh page the changes remains. Can anyone knows how to do that?

Here is the jsfiddle:
[enter link description here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NhT92/)

Comment: You can set a cookie on click

Comment: I think `localStorage` will be better here than cookies because this data is for the front-end.

Comment: Do you have an idea how this will be? I tried getElement, but didn't work

Comment: The JSfiddle link is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use `localStorage` to do this. Set `localStorage` when you change the state and then when the page loads, get `localStorage` and reset each `td` to how they were before based off the `localStorage` value:

Here's [my update for your JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NhT92/86/). Also, I only changed the JavaScript, so here's the JavaScript code for this:

```
//Get all of the tds:
var tds = $("td");
//Loop through all tds:
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    //Get the previous state of the td:
    var prevState = localStorage.getItem("state"+i);
    console.log(prevState);
    //If prevState is null, set it to "first":
    if (prevState === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("state"+i, "first");
    }
    //Otherwise, restore prevState:
    else {
        //Get the td:
        var cell = $(tds.get(i));
        //Depending on prevState:
        switch (prevState) {
            case "first":
                //Do nothing if it's in the first state because that's the default.
                break;
            case "second":
                //Add the class "red" if it's in the second state:
                cell.addClass("red");
                break;
            case "third":
                //Add the class "yellow" if it's in the third state:
                cell.addClass("yellow");
                break;
            default:
                //If it's something else, set it to "first":
                localStorage.setItem("state"+i, "first");
                prevState = "first";
                break;
        }
        //Set cell's data-state to prevState:
        cell.data("state", prevState);
    }
}

tds.click(function () {
    var cell = $(this),
        state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

    switch (state) {
        case 'first':
            cell.addClass('red');
            cell.data('state', 'second');
            break;
        case 'second':
            cell.addClass('yellow');
            cell.data('state', 'third');
            break;
        case 'third':
            cell.removeClass('red yellow');
            cell.data('state', 'first');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    //Update state:
    state = cell.data("state");
    //Get the index of the td:
    var index = tds.index(cell);
    //Set localStorage using index and state:
    localStorage.setItem("state"+index, state);
});
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much hun! This one works perfect, in both, android devices and computer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at **[Your fiddle updated](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NhT92/88/)**.

Yes you can use `Local Storage` Find examples in **[HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)**.

You just need to store index of the column and related class e.g. **{'1':'red','2':'yellow'...}** using `localStorage.setItem(index,class)`, when the user click, and in onload (inside ready function) you have to parse every `td` check if realated index is in `Local Storage`, if yes get the class by `localStorage.getItem()` function and add it to the `td` using `addClass()` function : :

**JS :**

```
//parse every td onload
$('td').each(function(index){

    //Add class to the current td if his index is already stored in localStorage
    if(localStorage.getItem(index)!=null){
        $(this).addClass(localStorage.getItem(index));
    }
});

$('td').click(function () {
    var cell = $(this),
        state = cell.data('state') || 'first'
        index = $(this).index();

    switch (state) {
        case 'first':
            localStorage.setItem(index, "red");
            cell.addClass('red');
            cell.data('state', 'second');
            break;
        case 'second':
            localStorage.setItem(index, "yellow");
            cell.addClass('yellow');
            cell.data('state', 'third');
            break;
        case 'third':
            localStorage.setItem(index, "");
            cell.removeClass('red yellow');
            cell.data('state', 'first');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need `data-index` because you can just use `$("td").index()` and `$("td").get()`.

Comment: Thank you Zakaria!, this one works too, although on android devices have a little bug on touch